# Проблема: Ко всем числам второго вектора добавляется последняя цифра из первого вектора

Tags: c++, stl

В общем, мне надо сделать программу с длинной арифметикой.
Проблема появилась на этапе считывания и переворота массива.
Ко всем числам второго вектора добавляется последняя цифра из первого вектора

Например при введённых:

```
25565
9264
```

Получается:

```
5 6 5 5 2
45 65 25 95
```

Когда надо:

```
5 6 5 5 2
4 6 2 9
```

Также если поменять местами код с обработкой вектора1 и вектора2, то проблема появляется уже у первого, а не второго вектора.

Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string ia, ib;
    vector<int> a;
    vector<int> b;
    getline(cin, ia);
    getline(cin, ib);

    for(int i = 0; i < ia.size(); i++) //Фигня через которую я превращаю строку в вектор цифр
    {
        char c[1] = { ia[i] };         //Берёт i-тый символ
        a.push_back(atoi(c));          //Запихивает в конец вектора цифру
    }
    std::reverse(a.begin(), a.end());  //Переворачивает вектор. Длинка же

    for(int i = 0; i < ib.size(); i++) //Аналогично, только для b
    {
        char c[1] = { ib[i] };
        b.push_back(atoi(c));
    }
    std::reverse(b.begin(), b.end());  //Также

    vector<int> r(fmax(a.size(), b.size()) + 1, 0); //Пока что эта строка не нужна


    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); cout << endl; //Вывод
    std::copy(b.begin(), b.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); cout << endl; //Вывод
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вроде ничего незаконного и не делаю... Хотя вроде строка `char c[1] = { ib[i] }` костыль. Но по-другому atoi ничего не принимал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну что ж, в ответ на "как держать микроскоп, чтоб было удобнее забивать гвозди", отвечу именно на заданный вопрос...

Вот это

```
    char c[1] = { ia[i] };         //Берёт i-тый символ
    a.push_back(atoi(c));          //Запихивает в конец вектора цифру
```

замените на

```
    a.push_back(ia[i]-'0');
```

Судя по всему, о том, что строка в C завершается нулевым символом, вам неизвестно?

Comment: То что завершается нулевым знаю. Думал, atoi обойдётся и без этого..

Comment: Как???!!!!!! Как он может обойтись без этого?!!!

Comment: Ну не знаю.. Может через sizeof найти размер массива символов и от него отталкиваться... В любом случае я понял свою ошибку с:. Спасибо огромное